# Which version(s) of Mac OS X have Ruby installed by default?

Tags: macos, ruby

I'm thinking about using Ruby to write an installation script, but I'm not sure if all major versions of Mac OS X install it by default.

Which version(s) of Mac OS X have the Ruby interpreter installed by default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Ruby download page](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) indicates that Tiger (10.4) and Leopard (10.5) both include Ruby. I can verify from machines in my own home that Lion (10.7), Mountain Lion (10.8), and Mavericks (10.9) all come with Ruby. I can't personally verify that Snow Leopard (10.6) contained Ruby, but it would be shocking if it was present in the previous and subsequent versions but not Snow Leopard.

If your target audience is people who bought their computers or upgraded their operating system on or after April 29, 2005, you should be safe using Ruby in your installer.

Answer (score 31):

- 14.0    ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin23]
- 13.2    ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]
- 12.1    ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
- 11.6.1  ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
- 10.15.7 ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
- 10.14   ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
- 10.13   ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
- 10.12   ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
- 10.11.2 ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
- 10.10.2 ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-04-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
- 10.9.0: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
- 10.8.5: ruby 1.8.7     (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
- 10.7.5: ruby 1.8.7     (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]

Comment: I am trying to use newer version of ruby and not to overwrite the OSX's own ruby installation, what is the proper way to do that? I am getting a permission issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293653/164148) when trying brenv.

Comment: Use Homebrew to install `rbenv` and then you can have any Ruby version in parallel.

Comment: `chruby` is a non-invasive way to do this.