# How to manage newer Ruby installations in macOS without intervening with the default Ruby installations?

Tags: macos, install, package-management, ruby

macOS comes with some default ruby installations, more [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107853/which-versions-of-mac-os-x-have-ruby-installed-by-default), that I do not want to overwrite by running gems commands as sudo. I tried rbenv, instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293653/164148), but I am getting a permission error in the last command `gem update --system` such that

```
brew update
brew install ruby
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile #bash
brew install rbenv ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile  # bash
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile               # bash
rbenv install 2.4.1
rbenv local 2.4.1
rbenv global 2.4.1
rbenv rehash
gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update 
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I do not want to intervene with the default ruby installation in macOS, not to get the need for a fresh installation of the whole OS.

**What is a proper way to install newer version of Ruby on macOS without intervening with the default ruby?**

*Further questions on Ruby in macOS*

1. [rbenv not overriding default Ruby version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205025/rbenv-not-overriding-default-ruby-version)
2. [How to install ruby gems without sudo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209256/how-to-install-ruby-gems-without-sudo)
3. [Which version(s) of Mac OS X have Ruby installed by default?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107853/which-versions-of-mac-os-x-have-ruby-installed-by-default)

Comment: The command you mentioned isn't included in the answer you refer to. Can you add the whole sequence of commands you've used?

Comment: Try to run the commands from `rbenv` onwards in a newly started shell so that the PATH gets set correctly.

Comment: @patrix I got the command run, by testing the last command in a new shell, but unable to install packages with gem, shown [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/288110/25260), this may be a small pkg-related problem or bigger problem, dunno yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you only update `PATH` etc in the shell profiles, but not in the running shell. Try to run the commands from `rbenv` onwards in a newly spawned shell.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, moved the question about LoadError [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288148/loaderror-in-installing-packages-such-as-oauth-with-ruby-gems-why).